# How to retrieve a value from Combobox and assign it to an Entity using springMVC and JSP

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, combobox

i would like to retrieve a value from combobox in jsp `<form:select />` which get its values from another Entity named Group, and assign it to a User. both of Entities are mapped together with `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne`. so many users can be assigned to one Group.
PS: the combobox Content is dynamic.

here is my Controller file:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/add")
public ModelAndView addUserPage() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/admin/user/addUser");
    List<Group> groups = groupService.listGroups();
    List<String> groupNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (Group m : groups) {
        groupNames.add(m.getGroupName());
    }
    mav.addObject("user", new User());
    mav.addObject("groupNames", groupNames);
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/add/process")
public ModelAndView addingUser(@ModelAttribute(value = "user") User user,
        @ModelAttribute(value = "groupName") String groupName) {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("redirect:/spring/user/list.html");
    user.setDateModification(new Date());
    Group group = groupService.getGroupByGroupName(groupName);
    user.setGroup(group);
    userService.addUser(user);
    String message = "User was successfully added.";
    mav.addObject("message", message);

    return mav;
}
```

and my JSP file:

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="user"
                                action="/myApplication/spring/user/add/process.html">
                                <label>username</label>
                                <form:input path="username" class="span12"></form:input>
                                <label>Password</label>
                                <form:input path="password" type="password" class="span12"></form:input>
                                <label>Groupe</label>
                                <form:select path="group">
                                    <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Choisir un groupe ---" />
                                    <form:options items="${groupNames}" />
                                </form:select>
                                <label>Code Banque</label>
                                <form:input path="codeBanque" class="span12"></form:input>
                                <label>Code Agence</label>
                                <form:input path="codeAgence" class="span12"></form:input>
                                <input value="Ajouter" type="submit"
                                    class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </form:form>
```

My goal is to assign the User to a Group threw the form of adding users. i was able to get one ModelAttribure which is user, but i can't get Two !

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed my problem and here is the solution:

UserController:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/add")
public ModelAndView addUserPage() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/admin/user/addUser");
    List<Group> groups = groupService.listGroups();
    mav.addObject("groups", groups);
    mav.addObject("user", new User());
    return mav;
}
```

and my Jsp page:

```
                        <label>Groupe</label>
                        <form:select path="group.idGroup" items="${groups}"
                            itemValue="idGroup" itemLabel="groupName" multiple="false"
                            class="span12">
                        </form:select>
```